# javax.annotation: @Nullable vs @CheckForNull

Tags: java, annotations, static-analysis, findbugs

What is the difference between the two? Both seem to mean that the value may be null and should be dealt with accordingly i.e. checked for null.

**Update:**
The two annotations above are part of JSR-305/FindBugs:
http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html

Comment: I don't think those annotations come from Java Bean Validation's API. What library/framework are you using? Doesn't it have documentation for it's annotations?

Comment: Neither seems to be part of a regular Java API. Where are they implemented?

Comment: Updated the description. It is part of JSR-305 and the implementation I am using is FindBugs.

Comment: worth noting that bug " overriding @Nullable parameter" http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1139/ has been fixed in findbugs. So we can override it with \@Nonull in implementations

Comment: these methods are also  part of Guava collection framework

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think it is pretty clear from the link you added: if you use `@CheckForNull` and the code that uses the value does not check for `null`, FindBugs will show it as an error.

FindBugs will ignore `@Nullable`.

> In practice this annotation is useful only for overriding an overarching `NonNull` annotation.

Use `@CheckForNull` in the cases when the value must always be checked. Use `@Nullable` where `null` might be OK.

EDIT: it seems that `@CheckForNull` is not well supported at the moment, so I suggest avoiding it and using `@NonNull` (also see [Which @NotNull Java annotation should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)). 
Another idea would be to get in touch directly with the FindBugs developers, and ask their opinion about the inconsistency in the documentation.

Comment: The only warning I got from FindBugs after running the code from Alexander's answer is

`nonnull() may return null, but is declared @NonNull At test.java:[line 19] In method com.db.icestation.test.nonnull()`

The bug descriptions is `Method may return null, but is declared @NonNull. This method may return a null value, but the method (or a superclass method which it overrides) is declared to return @NonNull. Bug kind and pattern: NP - NP_NONNULL_RETURN_VIOLATION`

Comment: I cannot find any mention of @CheckForNull here: http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html (@NonNull is there)

Comment: @vitaly - FindBugs 2.0.1 reports the `@CheckForNull` violation as [`NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE`](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE).

Comment: `@Nullable` specifically tells FindBugs to ignore the possibility of `null` just as it does for all non-annotated references. I believe you should never need to use it except maybe to deal with third-party code you cannot modify.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Sorry, I am not quite sure I can follow. The @Nullable annotation helps in cases like `System.out.println(new test().nullable().length());` from Alex' code. If I understand correctly, it specifically tells FindBugs to analyse possibility of `null`.

Comment: @vitaly - From a [summary of the nullness annotations](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jsr-305/mU-HqM4jwtk), Bill Pugh has this to say about `@Nullable`: "Because we allow for default annotations, we should also have an annotation that [is] exactly the same as having no nullness annotation of any kind." At the bottom he states the point is to allow for tools of varying strictness.

Answer (score 10):

`@Nonnull` and `@Nullable` are correctly handled by IntelliJ IDEA. FindBugs found the problem with `@Nonnull` but missed those for `@Nullable` and `@CheckForNUll`. Problems which were detected by IDEA and FindBugs are marked with comments.

```
package com.db.icestation;

import javax.annotation.CheckForNull;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class test {

    @Nullable public String nullable() {
        return "";
    }

    @Nonnull public String nonnull() {
        return null; // IDEA, findbugs
    }

    @CheckForNull public String checkForNull() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new test().nullable().length()); // IDEA
        System.out.println(new test().nonnull().length());
        System.out.println(new test().checkForNull().length());
    }
}
```

Comment: Eclipse finds exactly the same, **provided that** it is configured to perform 'Null analysis' and uses the correct annotations (by default it uses JDT annotations and not JSR-305).
Interestingly, there is no configuration for @CheckForNull annotation (but it has @NonNullByDefault).

Comment: FindBugs 2.0.1 detects the `@CheckForNull` case: "Possible null pointer dereference due to return value of called method."

Comment: @DavidHarkness - I can't reproduce it using 2.0.1: https://github.com/lischenko/flaming-ninja (see findbugs.null.analysis). findbugs-maven-plugin=v2.5.2 - the latest, annotations=2.0.1

Comment: @vitaly - I'm using the [Software Quality Environment plugin for NetBeans](http://kenai.com/projects/sqe/pages/Home) which includes FindBugs, and the message is tagged as coming from FindBugs. I included the 2.0.1 version in my project to get the annotations, but perhaps the plugin includes an older version (that works).

Comment: @vitaly - I installed FB 2.0.1 and have verified that it is not detecting the `@CheckForNull` annotation correctly. I cannot figure out which version of FB the SQE plugin uses.

Comment: If you use the JetBrains `@NotNull` annotation, IDEA instruments the code with added runtime checks, but if you use `@Nonnull`, it doesn't. I don't know about others, but that is pretty far from "correctly handled" in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

In the IntelliJ Idea `@javax.annotation.Nullable` is supported by default and any attempts to dereference `@Nullable` arguments or return values will result in warning.

@alexander-pavlov, You could add `@javax.annotation.CheckForNull` in configuration of "Constant conditions & exceptions" inspection. Go File->Settings->Inspections->Probable bugs->Constant conditions & exceptions->Configure annotations.

I prefer doing this as `@CheckForNull` has more clear meaning than `@Nullable` as @lbalazscs mentioned in his answer above.