# FindBugs @NonNull and @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, findbugs

Like described in [Set findbugs NotNull as default for all classes under a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310994/set-findbugs-notnull-as-default-for-all-classes-under-a-package) I annotated my packages so all class fields are automatically marked as `@NonNull`.

Now are all the `@Autowired` not nullable, too, which leads to many FindBugs errors that these fields are not initialized. Is there a config to tell FindBugs that all fields should be `@NonNull` except `@Autowired` fields?

Comment: could you attach a code snipped, an mark the errors?

Comment: @ NotNull doesn't automatically make sure that fields are not null, you still have to do it. From what it sounds like, your @Autowired is not triggering, hence the variable doesn't get initialized. Either your class is not annotated with @ Service / @ Component, your applicationContext.xml doesn't have annotatation scanning enabled or might be incorrectly setup. Please post some code snippets, especially your applicationContext.xml and your java class.