# Validation of null against Regex

Tags: java, regex, annotations

I am trying to validate a String in Java to see if it matches the randomUUID format using the following regex

```
^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}$
```

Now this works fine and picks up invalid strings and so on – however, if I pass a null String to the regex, it returns true, so when I perform validation on the Pattern annotation, no constraint violations are reported. Is this expected behaviour, since the String is null it is not performing any validation?

As a way around this, on the getter method that I have annotated with the Pattern annotation, I have used this

```
return id != null ? id : "null"
```

This works, however it seems a bit... hacky to me :)

Comment: Standard Java doesn't have `Pattern` annotation but only class. Are you using some frameworks?

Comment: I imagine passing a null string would generate a NullPointerException.  Can you add the code where you are actually applying the pattern?

Comment: I am using Hibernate annotations, as far as I know now when null is passed no regex check is performed so I assume that is what is going wrong with my code!

Comment: Hibernate has pattern annotation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to exclude nulls, use [a 'not null' annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use), such as `@NotNull`.

---

PatternValidator returns `true` if the argument is `null` (a weird choice, IMHO); it says so right in the source. I've seen different versions, and they all did this, so it's really part of the contract (and should be documented better).

```
public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    if ( value == null ) {
        return true;
    }
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher( value );
    return m.matches();
}
```

Comment: Yes, very strange, although I can understand how technically null does not equal the pattern...