Where does the inferred @NotNull come from?
I've been looking at Function.java from Microsoft\jdk-17.0.11.9-hotspot\lib\src.zip!\java.base\java\util\function\Function.java
It appears like this in IntelliJ IDEA 2024 :

I couldn't help but notice that there's an automated (inferred) @NotNull added by IntelliJ in front of Function<...> in the method prototype.
Where does the @NotNull come from? In other words : What does this class have that my own classes don't have? (None of my classes make IntelliJ add @NotNull spontaneously even when the context makes it clear).
Note: I looked at annotation @FunctionalInterface 's inner workings but could not find a direct link between how it works and this @NotNull. Maybe it's there, I just don't see it.

Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/22641830/5133585? Does that answer your question?

You say "none of my classes make IntelliJ add...", but do you see "@" signs in the gutter of your class' methods? The thing you see in Function.java is basically that, but displayed inline. See also: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html#show-inferred-annotations-inline

@Sweeper no I don't see any @ sign in the gutter of my classes. Only in Function.java and other built-in classes. As Michael has pointed out, that might be built-in. But in order to focus on my own code, I have enabled this setting which I didn't know exists : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/annotating-source-code.html#show-inferred-annotations-inline -> As a result, the gutter @ is not there yet but I'm getting closer.

There are only so many things IntelliJ can infer. compose is inferred to be @NotNull because it returns a lambda, which can never be null. Try writing a method that returns a lambda too, and IntelliJ should be able to infer @NotNull. Returning a string literal also works.

"compose is inferred to be @NotNull because it returns a lambda, which can never be null" That's not a sensible thing to infer for a default interface method, because it can be overridden by something that does return null. If it was static or final, sure.

@jeancallisti I found where it comes from after a lot of digging and updated my answer.

You seem to be making the assumption that your code should work exactly like standard library code, and that's not the case.
IntelliJ has special handling baked in for certain library code. In this case, it comes from an XML file, but there are also some other code paths and certain hardcoded things. IntelliJ calls these "external annotations", and you can add your own too.
<item name='java.util.function.Function java.util.function.Function&lt;V,R&gt; compose(java.util.function.Function&lt;? super V,? extends T&gt;)'>
    <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract'>
        <val name="pure" val="true"/>
    </annotation>
    <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull'/>
</item>

Intuitively, we can see that that default implementation will never return null. It either throws or returns a function.
The reason IntelliJ doesn't infer the annotation, even if you copy and paste the same code to a new file, is that just because the default implementation doesn't return null, that doesn't imply that implementers are not allowed to. For all IntelliJ knows, implementers are allowed to return null. It needs this extra data to give the method a stronger contract than it can infer.
