# Is there a way to annotate a class to apply an annotation to every inner element in java?

Tags: java, package, notnull

Specifically a class annotation to apply a NotNull annotations(like those presented in [Which @NotNull Java annotation should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)) by default to all fields, method return and parameters in the class.

Or a package annotation to apply NotNull annotations to every fields, method return and parameters in every class in the package.

Comment: How do you want to use this? With a validation framework?

Comment: I think it might depend Annotation provider,which want to interpret it.