# Cannot annotate with both @NonNull and @NonNull

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, non-nullable

I am using IntelliJ 13.1.5 and Java 8 SDK and I've set up IntelliJ built-in nullness checker to use `checkers.nullness.quals.NonNull` as the annotation of my choice.

Now, when I write a simple class like this

```
import checkers.nullness.quals.NonNull;

public class Myclass  {
    public void doSomething(@NonNull String someString) {
    }
}
```

IntelliJ underlines the `@NonNull` annotation with the warning

> Cannot annotate with both @NonNull and @NonNull

First I thought it has something to do with classes that implement interface which also have methods annotated with `@NonNull`.

But I also happens with concrete classes like the example above.

My next guess was that multiple libraries use the same annotation name and there might be a name clash. But unfortunately the warning doesn't specify the exact class name with packages. If this is the case, there must be some setting that enables implicit annotations.

How can I get rid of this warning without removing the annotation?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use

Answer (score 2):

I've just got a reply to be issue that helped me resolve the problem. I'm still not sure if this was my fault or if this is a bug, but here is the solution:

IntelliJ has (at least) two locations in the project settings where you can configure the nullness annotations which are:

1. Settings | Inspections | Constant conditions & exceptions | Configure annotations
2. Settings | Inspections | @NotNull/@Nullable problems | Configure annoations

When I set up the annotations, added them using 1.) not knowing there is 2.). The issue was cause because in 2.), the annotation `checkers.nullness.quals.NonNull` was selected in both the `Nullable` and `NonNull` sections which is obviously wrong. In 1.) everything was fine.

To resolve the issue, I removed `checkers.nullness.quals.NonNull` from the `Nullable` section in 2.) and added and selected `checkers.nullness.quals.Nullable`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in IDEA. For historical reasons, many toolkits will treat any annotations with certain simple names (like `NonNull`) as equivalent, and it looks like IDEA may have some collisions. You should report this as a bug to JetBrains.

Comment: There is an internal `NonNull` annotation in openapi (intellij core) iirc. I'm not sure if this could be where the conflict lies.