# How to add new fields in all documents in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

Lets say I have 100 documents with fields

`Name`
`Age`
`Address`

Now suppose my business model is change and I want to add new field call `PhoneNumber`.

How to add field `PhoneNumber` in all 100 documents ?
Is is possible to such stuff on NoSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write code to iterate all the documents to update, then actually update a new value in each one of them.  Firestore has no similar command as "update tablename set x=y where ..." in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

> Is is possible to such stuff on NoSQL database?

Yes it is! Assuming you have a `User` model class that look like this:

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber; //Property that is newly added

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, int age, String address, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }

    public String getAddress() { return address; }
    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }

    public String getPhoneNumber() { return phoneNumber; }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) { this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber; }
}
```

To actually add a new property and update it accordingly, you need to use setters. If you are setting the values directly onto the public fields, the setters are not mandatory.

> How to add field PhoneNumber in all 100 documents?

As also @Doug Stevenson mentioned in his answer, to solve this, you need to iterate all the documents within your `users` collection. So please use the following lines of code:

```
db.collection("users").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                User user = document.toObject(User.class);
                user.setPhoneNumber("+1-111-111-111"); //Use the setter
                String id = document.getId();
                db.collection("users").document(id).set(user); //Set user object
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The result of this code would be to add the `phoneNumber` property to all you `User` objects with a default value of `+1-111-111-111`. You can also set the value to `null` if it's more convenient for you. At the end, the updated object is set right on the corresponding reference.

If you are not using a model class, please see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070668/cloud-firestore-how-to-set-a-field-in-document-to-null/54071216#54071216)**.