# Expression might evaluate to null but is returned by the method declared as @NotNull

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After creating a RecyclerView adapter a warning about my view holder is returned. I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381447/could-this-call-to-getstring-actually-return-null) and understand it a bit, but it's not clear as to what the `viewHolder` instance in `return viewHolder;` should be replaced with.

> Expression might evaluate to null but is returned by the method declared as @NotNull

```
public class MyRVAapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private final static int TYPE_EXPANDABLE = 1, TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE = 2;
    private ArrayList callSMSFeed = new ArrayList();
    private Context context;

    public MyRVAapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void setCallSMSFeed(List<Object> callSMSFeed){
        this.callSMSFeed = (ArrayList) callSMSFeed;
    }

  @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (callSMSFeed.get(position) instanceof Phonecall) {
            return TYPE_EXPANDABLE;
        } else if (callSMSFeed.get(position) instanceof SMSmessage) {
            return TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        int viewType=holder.getItemViewType();
        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_EXPANDABLE:
                Phonecall call = (Phonecall) callSMSFeed.get(position);
                ((CallViewHolder)holder).showCallDetails(call);
                break;
            case TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE:
                SMSmessage sms = (SMSmessage)callSMSFeed.get(position);
                ((SMSViewHolder)holder).showSmsDetails(sms);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){return callSMSFeed.size();}

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


        int layout;

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder;
        switch (viewType){
            case TYPE_EXPANDABLE:
                layout = R.layout.cardview_a;
                View callsView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new CallViewHolder(callsView);
                break;
            case TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE:
                layout = R.layout.cardview_b;
                View smsView = LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(layout, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new SMSViewHolder(smsView);
                break;
            default:
                viewHolder = null;
                break;
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like @TheWanderer's answer, but I wanted to add another in order to highlight something that I think will make your life easier.

Unlike `ListView`, `RecyclerView` doesn't care what values you return from `getItemViewType()`; as long as you return distinct values from this method, `RecyclerView` is happy. This allows you to use layout resource ids as return values, which means you never have to define your own constants!

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    Object obj = callSMSFeed.get(position);

    if (obj instanceof Phonecall) {
        return R.layout.cardview_a;
    } else if (obj instanceof SMSmessage) {
        return R.layout.cardview_b;
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException("item at position " + position + " is not a Phonecall or SMSmessage: " + obj);
}
```

Here we return `R.layout.cardview_a` instead of `TYPE_EXPANDABLE`; both are `int`s under the hood, but now we can let the Resources framework take care of defining them for us.

We also throw an exception if we ever hit an `Object` that isn't a `Phonecall` or `SMSmessage` so that we know right away that there's a case we need to handle. This sort of exception should only be seen by developers making mistakes; the app won't ever crash on a user because you'll go ahead and fix the crash before you release the app.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(viewType, parent, false);

    switch (viewType) {
        case R.layout.cardview_a:
            return new CallViewHolder(itemView);

        case R.layout.cardview_b:
            return new SMSViewHolder(itemView);

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected viewType: " + viewType);
    }
}
```

Because we returned layout ids from `getItemViewType()`, we don't have to worry about translating from our own constants to `R.layout` values; we can just inflate the `viewType` directly. We still need the `switch` statement, though, to know which type of `ViewHolder` to return.

Again, we thrown an exception here in case we are ever passed a `viewType` we don't expect. This "won't happen", but if it ever *does*, it will be very clear where the problem is and easy for you to fix.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = holder.getItemViewType();

    switch (viewType) {
        case R.layout.cardview_a:
            Phonecall call = (Phonecall) callSMSFeed.get(position);
            ((CallViewHolder) holder).showCallDetails(call);
            break;

        case R.layout.cardview_b:
            SMSmessage sms = (SMSmessage) callSMSFeed.get(position);
            ((SMSViewHolder) holder).showSmsDetails(sms);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("unexpected viewType: " + viewType);
    }
}
```

Here the only difference is replacing your constants with layout ids inside the `switch`. No big deal. And, of course, we crash if we get something we don't expect.

Note also that I've removed the `final` keyword from the params. Even though the compiler will happily let you add them, you shouldn't do it. Because of methods like `notifyItemInserted()`, it's possible for a `ViewHolder`'s position to change over time without ever being re-bound. Dealing with this is outside the scope of your question, but it's something to point out.

Answer (score 4):

@NonNull is just an IDE flag (and used for Kotlin cross-compatibility). It doesn't do much more than tell the IDE when it should and shouldn't warn you about potential null pointers.

Just because you declare it doesn't mean your method will return a non-null value. Of course, yours will just because of how it works, but the IDE isn't that smart. All it sees is a contradiction: you use the @NonNull parameter, but you also have a case where you return a null value.

<s>The easiest way to fix this would be to just replace your `default` case with what's under `TYPE_EXPANDABLE` or `TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE` and remove the redundant case, ie:</s>

EDIT: From Ben P's comment, it would also be a good idea to throw an Exception in your `onCreateViewHolderMethod()` if the current View type is unexpected.

```
switch (viewType){
    case TYPE_EXPANDABLE:
        layout = R.layout.cardview_a;
        View callsView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new CallViewHolder(callsView);
        break;
    case TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE:
        layout = R.layout.cardview_b;
        View smsView = LayoutInflater
                .from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new SMSViewHolder(smsView);
        break;
    default:
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid View type: " + viewType);
}
```

<s>It's not the most elegant, but as long as you know for sure that `getItemViewType()` can never return `-1`, you won't run into any weird behavior.</s>

I would add one more thing to this, though, just so you can be sure you'll get what you want. Instead of this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (callSMSFeed.get(position) instanceof Phonecall) {
        return TYPE_EXPANDABLE;
    } else if (callSMSFeed.get(position) instanceof SMSmessage) {
        return TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Try this:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (callSMSFeed.get(position) instanceof Phonecall) {
        return TYPE_EXPANDABLE;
    } else if (callSMSFeed.get(position) instanceof SMSmessage) {
        return TYPE_NONEXPANDABLE;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Item at position " + position + " is not an instance of either Phonecall or SMSmessage");
}
```

Note: You can use whichever Exception type you think is fit for the case. I'm using IllegalArgumentException, Ben P (from comments) might use IllegalStateException... you could even just throw Exception.

Comment: I agree with most of this answer. I especially like throwing at the end of `getItemViewType()` (though I would personally choose `IllegalStateException` or `AssertionError`)... but I would say that you should _also_ throw in `onCreateViewHolder()` if the `viewType` argument is something you don't expect. Much better for your app to crash if you get passed some third option you don't expect (maybe you later change `getItemViewType()` but forget to change `onCreateViewHolder()`) than to return the wrong `ViewHolder`.

Answer (score 0):

You have this

```
@NonNull
```

before your `onCreateViewHolder`. The warning message is clearly telling you that you need to make sure you return something which is not `null`. In the case of `default`, `viewHolder` is `null` indeed, you might want to return a valid value, or throw an exception in that case.

Answer (score 0):

you have this warning because the method

```
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
```

must not return null, but on your default case you are returning null

```
default:
                viewHolder = null;
                break;
```

On production, the default case will lead to a crash, and that is why the warning is rised. 
You have to throw a runtime Exception or return a default non null view.