# Javax @NotNull annotation usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a simple method to get a list of documents for a given `companyId`. Here is the method:

```
@Override
public List<Documents> getDocumentList(@NotNull Integer companyId) {
    Company company = new Company(companyId);
    return this.documentRepository.findByCompany(company);
}
```

I wanted to use Javax validation constraints to ensure that the `companyId` being passed in, is not `null`. But it seems to not have any effect, as I'm able to pass in a `null` value, and it flows down to the `findByCompany` call on the repository. I also added `@Valid` before `@NotNull` to force validation, but that too didn't do anything.

I could always write a couple of lines to check for a `null` value, but wanted to use `javax.validation` annotations to make the code more readable and concise. Is there a way to make the annotations work on method params?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To activate parameter validation, simply annotate the class with `@Validated`

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
```

Comment: What if I ain't using spring

Comment: You could use @NonNull from projectlombok (lombok.NonNull)

Comment: Adding more annotations will have any impact on performance? As adding one more layer before actual method gets invoked?

Comment: @Validated's impact is negligible to none

Comment: This doesn't work for me. NotNull on method params and Validated on the class.

Answer (score 2):

From The Java EE 6 Tutorial:

> The Bean Validation model is supported by constraints in the form of
>   annotations placed on a field, method, or class **of a JavaBeans**
>   **component**, **such as a managed bean**.

You should place your validation of a field related to a declared bean, something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class BackgammonUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name="username")
    @NotBlank
    private String userName;

    @NotBlank
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled;
}
```

The BackgammonUser is considered to be a bean.

Comment: I am aware of this. I did not want to create a bean for a single param

Comment: Then it's a limitation. you can look it up as well in The Java EE 6 Tutorial

Comment: Thank you. I guess, I have to write the null check manually after all :)

Comment: Can we use the @NotNull annotation on the Entity class, instead of checking for each variable ??

Answer (score 0):

If you `@Inject` a class with your method, its working as expected.

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean{ 
    @Inject
    TestClass test;
}
```

and

```
public class TestClass {
    public List<Documents> getDocumentList(@NotNull Integer companyId)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

`ConstraintViolationException` when you call your method with null parameter:

```
WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component MyBean for method ...:
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException:
1 constraint violation(s) occurred during method validation.
```

Answer (score -6):

@NotNull Annotation,

1. A method should not return null.
2. A variable (like fields, local variables, and parameters) cannot hold null value.

Comment: Downvote as providing some general programming hints inapropriate to the question does not help anyone. And furthermore your second statement is confusing / incomplete (or wrong if meant as written).