# Consuming Json in JAX-RS: Prohibiting null values

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, jboss7.x, java-ee-8

I'm writing a simple REST service which expects a POST containing a Json.
The service should refuse any Json not containing exactly the keys it expects.
I'm using JAX-RS on a JBoss EAP 7.1 and have been unable to do this. Code example:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/")
@Stateless
@Produces("text/plain")
public class TestAccess
{
  @POST
  @Path("test/")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String consumeJson(TestClass c)
  {
    return c.toString();
  }

}
```

```
public class TestClass
{
  public String first;
  public String second;

  public String toString()
  {
    return (first + ", " + second);
  }
}
```

Previously I wrote `consumeJson` to expect expect a `JsonObject` and parsed that using a Jackson `ObjectMapper`. Doing this resulted in an error when receiving a Json missing keys. I think the way I'm doing it now is a "cleaner" way to do it as now the parameter list clearly shows what kind of Object the Json should describe. However, I don't want to check every single field first thing in the method nor do I want to add a `isValid()` method to every Object I get this way.

The example `{"first" : "contentOfFirst"}` returns `"contentOfFirst, null"` instead of failing.

EDIT: To clarify, I attempted something like this:

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class TestClass
{
  @NotNull
  public String first;
  @NotNull
  public String second;

  public String toString()
  {
    return (first + ", " + second);
  }
}
```

This did not change the outcome, instead of failing (as it was supposed to) the POST still got the response `"contentOfFirst, null"`. I'm aware these annotations still need a validator to validate them. I was (falsely?) under the impression that Jboss provides such a validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I missed that you need another annotation to enforce the checks:

```
  @POST
  @Path("test/")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public String consumeJson(@Valid TestClass c)
  {
    return c.toString();
  }
```

That's all that's needed for JBoss to actually enforce the checks.

It should be noted that JBoss doesn't like the use of `@Valid` and generic classes (like `List<PathSegment>`) in the same parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

Modern jackson versions have @JsonCreator & @JsonProperty to do some validation during deserialization, e.g. for you case:

```
public class TestClass
{
    @JsonCreator
    TestClass(
            @JsonProperty(value = "first", required = true) Integer first,
            @JsonProperty(value = "second", required = true) Integer second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second= second;
    }
    public String first;
    public String second;

    public String toString()
    {
        return (first + ", " + second);
    }
}
```

More robust solution would be to use [Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/)

Comment: As noted in my original post I'm aware of annotations like `@NotNull`. I was unsuccessful in utilizing those, however. The framework doesn't seem to respect the annotations.

Comment: I didn't write anyting about `@NotNull`, sorry. It is for documentation purposes. There is a [separate thread on this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094039/using-notnull-annotation-in-method-argument).
Please check documentation for [JsonCreator](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html).
Or create failing testcase.