# When is it appropriate to annotate something as @NotNull in Java?

Tags: java

This is my first question on here and I'm pretty new to Java, so please pardon me if this is kind of a silly question.

I am working on "documenting" the expected behavior of my application from within using JavaDocs and annotations, but I'm just curious if it's appropriate or good practice to use `@NotNull` on a method that SHOULDN'T ever return null, but may due to future developer error.

Thanks.

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34094352/4207306)

Answer (score 3):

This really depends on what tooling you're using. The `@NotNull` annotation doesn't actually *do* anything. Actually, [there are several different `@NotNull` annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use?rq=1) provided by different libraries. None of them do anything on their own, other than signalling the programmer's intent.

To make the annotation do anything, you need to combine it with a tool that will process the annotation (either at compile time or at run time) and apply some validation to your code or your data. For example:

- IntelliJ IDEA [contains tools which will check](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) that your code abides by the nullability annotations you've included.
- [Bean validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) can be used at runtime to check, for example, that user input doesn't violate the nullability constraints.

Even without the tooling, I would say that yes, these annotations can be useful to signal intent. You can always remove the annotation if it becomes untrue.

It sounds like it would be a good idea in your case for all contributors to the codebase to use a tool, like IntelliJ IDEA, that will check for compliance with these annotations at compile time. That will help you to avoid the type of developer error that you describe.

Comment: @Harish Dalmia's answer suggests that NotNull is "an explicit contract", meaning, in my mind, it does enforce boundary conditions.

Comment: @hd1 yes, I think the wording about "an explicit contract" comes from the IDEA documentation that I linked to. The term "contract" normally (and in this case) refers to a claim about the behaviour of a piece of code which is not enforced by syntax or by the type system, but may be checked by tests or extra optional tooling.

Comment: "contract" to me refers to Eiffel, which does enforce contracts as design -- https://www.eiffel.org/doc/solutions/Design_by_Contract_and_Assertions

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is not enforced standard globally to use these types of annotations. It makes sense to use them when writing a public API, but this is project specific.

In any case, feel free to do so in your project if it would help with code clarity and readability.

**It's not an anti-pattern to have javadocs with annotations**.

---

Also, if you are considering of warning the user of your method that it *shouldn't* return a `null`, but there is a chance of that happening (since you cannot enforce it), you might want to look into the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is good practice to use @NotNull. The @NotNull Annotation is, actually, an explicit contract declaring the following:

1. A method should not return null.
2. A variable (like fields, local variables, and parameters)cannot hold a null value.

So to keep it simple, it is a good practice.

Comment: @Sam's comment suggests it "doesn't actually do anything.", whereas yours does. Please reconcile your answers