# Enforce super call on non constructor methods

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

Is it possible to enforce an overriden method to call the superclass method? Constructors always need to call their superclass constructor. But i want to enforce this on normal methods, without the position of when it is called mattering.

Example:

```
public class A {

    public void doSth() {
        System.out.println("I must appear on console!");
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void doSth() {
        System.out.println("Bla!");  // IDE should mark an error, because supermethod is not called.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not strictly Java related, I was looking for an answer to this issue as it relates to Android and found the annotation in the support annotations library called "@CallSuper". It does exactly what you think, and throws a lint error if the subclass does not call the super's implementation of methods annotated with @CallSuper.

That solved my usecase, but again, I know that the solution is strictly tied with Android. Please let me know if that is too far off base and I will remove the answer.

Here is some more documentation on @CallSuper.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/CallSuper.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html (just search for CallSuper and it'll show right up in that second link.

Comment: I don't remember in which case i was asking for this, but i'm sure it was android related, so thank you! :)

Comment: You're quite welcome! I hope you're able to use this in your future projects. Let me know if you run into any other questions.

Answer (score 9):

No, that is not possible. It is entirely up to the overriding method to call the superclass method, or not.

However, there is a way to do it, if you want to enforce control.

This is called the [Template Method Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html). Whether the template methods are abstract or stubs (like shown here), depends on whether they must do something, or simply allow something extra to be done.

```
public class A {
    public final void doSth() { // final, preventing override by subclasses
        beforeDoSth();
        System.out.println("I must appear on console!");
        afterDoSth();
    }
    protected void beforeDoSth() { // protected, since it should never be called directly
        // Stub method, to be overridden by subclasses, if needed
    }
    protected void afterDoSth() {
        // Stub method, to be overridden by subclasses, if needed
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    protected void afterDoSth() {
        System.out.println("Bla!");
    }
}
```

If you then execute `new B().doSth()`, you'll get:

```
I must appear on console!
Bla!
```

Comment: It's not _entirely_ up to the overriding method. If the super class is designed so that the method returns a type that cannot be created by the subclass, then there is no option but to call the super implementation from the subclass.

Comment: @MickMnemonic If you want to nitpick like that ;-), I could respond by saying that overriding method could choose to not call super and return `null`. ;-P

Comment: Now _that's_ nitpicking! But good point; the return value should be specified as `@Nonnull` so that no contract-abiding subclass could avoid the `super` call.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.  If you allow a method to be overridden at all (by not declaring it or its class `final`) then you cannot control much of anything about the implementation of methods that override it.  You can, however, *document* that such methods should invoke the superclass's version.  There's only so much you can do to protect your users from themselves.

You may also find that there are alternative designs that would suit you better.  For example, if you want to allow subclasses to override particular details of a computation, but not to override the whole computation altogether, then you could employ the Template Method pattern.  In that case, the computation is driven by one "template" method, which you can declare `private` or `final` if you wish, and the customizable details are implemented in a separate, non-`final`, `public` or `protected`, possibly `abstract` method that the driver method calls where appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. It is up to the overriding method to call or to not call the method that it overrides.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, given the following constraints:

- The method has  a non-`void` return type
- Subclasses (or other classes accessible by the subclasses) cannot create instances of the return type

As @Andreas pointed out, the `super` call could still be avoided by returning `null`. In practice, this shouldn't be a problem, but it's reasonable to enforce non-nullness in the contract (super class documentation) and also by using [a null-preventing annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use), e.g. `@Nonnull`, so that any modern IDE can give a compile error when the super class method is not called.

For example:

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class A {

    public static final class Result {
        private Result() {
            // declare constructor private so the class cannot be 
            // instantiated from outside
        }        
    }

    /**
     * Does something.
     * 
     * @return the result; never {@code null}
     */
    public @Nonnull Result doSth() {
        System.out.println("I must appear on console!");
        return new Result();
    }
}

//...
public class B extends A {

    @Override
    public @Nonnull Result doSth() {
        System.out.println("Bla!");

        // only way to get a Result instance is through super.doSth()
        Result res = super.doSth();

        /* manipulate the result as needed */

        return res;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, i like it, but i can't inherit from a class with only constructor beeing private.

Comment: You're not inheriting from `Result`, you're inheriting from `A`.

Comment: Ohh yeah... True. And for Performance i could always return the same object, instead of creating a new one all the time.