# Enforcement of constructor-like base calls for non-constructor virtual methods?

Tags: c#

I have a multi-level class hierarchy with a `Refresh` method where each level introduces some new fields to be refreshed. In other words, I want the "level 3" class to refresh the fields of levels 1, 2 and 3, and the "level 4" class to refresh that of levels 1, 2, 3 and 4.

The basic solution is that each `Refresh` method calls `base.Refresh`. But I find this to be easy to overlook. I wish there was a way to annotate the root `Refresh` declaration to say that I want "constructor-like base call logic" on that method, i.e, please insert a call to `base.Refresh` before my method body for all children of that hierarchy. (If I can choose between pre and post-body i.e destructor-like, that's even better).

As far as I know there's no such thing in the base language, but I figure it's a common issue so perhaps some library introduces C# annotations that allow doing just that, as in the answer to [Enforce super call on non constructor methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231241/enforce-super-call-on-non-constructor-methods), or some suitable alternative. Is there ?

Comment: So `Level3 l = new Level4(); l.Refresh()` <-- should that refresh the level 4 fields or not?

Comment: Yes for that use case !

Comment: Note that base constructors are not called implicitly either - you have to explicitly call `base(...)` in subclass constructors if you want to call base constructors. So I'm not sure what mechanism you're thinking of here.

Comment: I'm thinking of a hypothetical library that would let me write `@PrependBaseCalls` as an attribute on the level 1 method call. Although that would open the possibility of someone prepending the base call manually when the attribute already takes care of that...

Comment: Mark every "refreshng" field with an attribute; Discover and refresh 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/156319/1704458

Comment: Template method pattern may help you.

Comment: Presumably not what you want to hear. But a.) multi levels of inheritance isn't really something you should do. Composition is preferred since ages. b.) If you fear the  call could be forgotten to propagate the refresh have unittest for it.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "refresh" really. Can you generalise this mechanism, and e.g. have the base class keep a list of fields to refresh, which derived classes add to in their ctor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this behavior with AOP and one of the libraries for Aspects.

For example you can add [`PostSharp`](https://www.postsharp.net/) to your project then define an aspect class that implements the "Refresh" method and applies it to the target classes using attributes.

```
public class RefreshCallAspect : MethodInterceptionAspect
{
    public override void OnInvoke(MethodInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Method.Name == "Refresh")
        {
            // here you should find and call a method of a base class
            base.OnInvoke(args);
        }
        args.Proceed();
    }
}

[RefreshCallAspect]
public class Level1
{
    public virtual void Refresh()
    {
        // Level 1 refresh logic here
    }
}

public class Level2 : Level1
{
    public override void Refresh()
    {
        // Level 2 refresh logic here
    }
}

public class Level3 : Level2
{
    public override void Refresh()
    {
        // Level 3 refresh logic here
    }
}
```

Here is an article about [Intercepting Methods](https://doc.postsharp.net/method-interception) in PostSharp.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll look into what you can do with PostSharp. I wonder if the attribute could be on the method rather than the class.