# where is NotNull in java?

Tags: java

I want to compile simple code with oracle jdk 1.8:

```
class Foo {
   public static void test(@NotNull String a) {}
}
```

But `idea` not understand such code, and suggest to add:

```
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
```

after that compilation inside `idea` works,
but if run build by `gradle` with such `build.gradle`:

```
version '1.0-snaphshot_03.03.2017'

apply plugin: 'java'

targetCompatibility = '1.8'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}
```

I got error:

```
error: package com.sun.istack.internal does not exist
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

 error: cannot find symbol
    public static void test(@NotNull String a) {
                                  ^
  symbol:   class NotNull
  location: class Foo
```

I thought that `NotNull` was added in `1.8`?
How can I make possible of usage of `NotNull` in `idea` and `gradle`?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use. I think it is @NonNull.

Comment: Do you mean `javax.annotation.Nonnull`?

Comment: Try Optional<T> instead.

Answer (score 7):

There is no `@NotNull` annotation in the standard JDK that would be meant for general use (the `com.sun.internal.istack.NotNull` is definitely not for your usage, as it's an internal class).

The Java Bean validation framework (JSR-303) has `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`, which is implemented by (for example)  Hibernate validator. That's *probably* what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be adding `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull` as this is Used by IntelliJ IDEA IDE for static analysis.
Refer : 
[IntelliJ Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html)
[This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)