# JUnit testing assertions

Tags: java, junit

I need to build Junit test cases for the following code and I am trying to have one of the tests test that the  `assert s1 != null : "Violation of: s1 is not null";`, `assert s2 != null : "Violation of: s2 is not null";`, and `assert s1.length() >= 1 : "|s1| >= 1";` statements gives an error when a null sequence is passed or when `s1`'s length is >= 1.

I don't know the exact way of going about doing this.

A couple forums suggested using "Try Catch" but I don't know exactly how that works.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static void itersmooth(Sequence<Integer> s1, Sequence<Integer> 
    s2){
  assert s1 != null : "Violation of: s1 is not null";
  assert s2 != null : "Violation of: s2 is not null";
  assert s1.length() >= 1 : "|s1| >= 1";
  s2.clear();
  if (s1.length() > 1){
    int inp1 = 1;
    for (int inp2 = 0; inp2 < (s1.length() - 1); inp2++){
      int valone = s1.remove(inp2);
      int valtwo = s1.remove(inp1 - 1);
      int valoneT = valone / 2;
      int valtwoT = valtwo / 2;

      int valtemp = valoneT + valtwoT;
      if ((valone % 2 != 0 || valtwo % 2 != 0) && (valone > 0 && valtwo > 0)) {
        valtemp++;
      }
      if ((valone % 2 != 0 || valtwo % 2 != 0) && (valone < 0 && valtwo < 0)){
        valtemp--;
      }
      s2.add(inp2, valtemp);
      s1.add(inp2, valone);
      s1.add(inp1, valtwo);
      inp1++;
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Java's `assert` keyword is not the same as `JUnit.assert()`. Or is this your class-under-test?

Comment: In the `JUnit` code, you do something like `try { intersmooth(null, null); fail("Didn't catch"); } catch (Exception e) { //ensure e.getMessage() has s1 in it }`. Vary s1 and s2 as necessary.

Comment: Note that, [by default, assertions are disabled at runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable).

Answer (score 2):

I would not use Java's assertions to guard against `null` references, mainly because that feature can be -- [and by default is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable) -- turned off. This can lead into really hard-to-spot bugs, if your test system has assertions enabled and your production system does not.

Instead, I would use a preconditions library such as [Guava Preconditions](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) or [Apache Commons Validate](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html) for this purpose. In addition to this, I would annotate the method arguments with a ["NotNull" annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use), e.g. `javax.annotation.Nonnull`, so that client code will get compile-time protection in a modern IDE.

So, the method signature and the guard conditions would become like this (using Commons Validate):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

//...
public static void itersmooth(@Nonnull Sequence<Integer> s1, 
                              @Nonnull Sequence<Integer> s2) {
       Validate.notNull(s1, "Violation of: s1 is not null");
       Validate.notNull(s2, "Violation of: s2 is not null");
       Validate.isTrue(s1.length() >= 1, "|s1| >= 1");

       // ...
   }
```

After this change, writing the unit test is simple, because the method is guaranteed to throw a `NullPointerException` for failing the `notNull` check, or an `IllegalArgumentException`, for failing the `isTrue` check; you don't need to worry about assertions being enabled or not.

An example test for checking that a passed-in first argument can't be `null`, would look like this:

```
@Test(expected=NullPointerException.class)
public void throwsWhenFirstSequenceIsNull() {
    MyClass.itersmooth(null, new Sequence<Integer>(1,2,3));
    Assert.fail("Null argument didn't cause an exception!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with the other answer, but one subtle variation: in case you  prefer solutions that do **not** add dependencies on external libraries such as guava or apache, Java has a nice "built-in" thingy for that since Java7.

You can replace

```
assert s1 != null : "Violation of: s1 is not null";
```

with

```
Objects.requireNonNull(s1, "s1 must not be null");
```

Note: don't mix the two arguments - the first one is checked against null.

Beyond that: you should work on your naming skills. s1 and s2 ... mean nothing. They don't tell the reader anything about the *purpose* of those two variables. Same for most other names in that method. Try to use names that give information about the intended *purpose* of the thing behind the variable!

And beyond that: your **whole** code is extremely hard to read. It looks overly complex; and even after reading it 5 times; I still have no idea what it is supposed to do.

So the **real** answer here is: you absolutely want to learn about **clean code** (for example by reading the very book by Robert Martin) in order to improve on **that** level. Those asserts are just one aspect of many other problems in your source code ...

Comment: Using `Objects` could actually be the preferred way to do this for smaller projects/school work where you don't need the other good stuff from Guava/Commons.

Comment: Nonetheless: you covered all the relevant parts. So let's add the upvote I forgot while writing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use @Rule in your test class

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();   

public void testCase() {
    exception.expect(AssertionError.class);
    MyClass.itersmooth(null, new Sequence<Integer>(1,2,3));
}
```