# How to only validate field in entity Hibernate with hibernate validator when that field is not null or not empty

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently using the Hibernate-validator 4.2.0 as well as the javax.validator-api.1.0.0 for form validation,this works well for individual fields. But I want only validate when fields is not null or not empty, if fields is null or is empty then not validate. 
Can anyone help me solve this problem ? Thank you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use