# Is it possible to document that return value is not null with Java Optional?

Tags: java, option-type, non-nullable

Is it possible to document that return value is not `null` with Java `Optional`?

[Most tools and frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use) care only about arguments but I'd like to express in type that return value is not `null` (instead of doing that in JavaDoc).

**UPDATE** Looks like you can agree with team to use `Optional` as return value if you want to express possible `null` and direct object when it is definitely not null:

```
public Optional<Job> getJob() {  ... }
public Job extractJob(NonNullJobHolder<Job> holder) { ... }
```

Comment: If you return Optional, then you should never return null, no need for documentation

Comment: There is `Optional.of` which forbid `null`. Is there subclass of Optional that itself says container has value? Or it is not possible to use sub-type due to type erasure of generics?

Comment: Sounds like you need to just... read the Optional documentation and experiment with Optional. You seem to be operating under a couple of pretty serious misconceptions, and the documentation is good enough to sort them out for you.

Comment: Returning non-null values should be the normal state of things;  it should be implied.  It is methods which actually can return null that need to be explicitly documented as doing so.  (Whether that should be done with Optional depends on the method and the design;  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type for an authoritative answer.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know why you're under the impression that most of them apply only to parameters.

**org.eclipse.jdt.annotation.NonNull**

```
@Documented
@Retention(value=CLASS)
@Target(value={FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,LOCAL_VARIABLE})
public @interface NonNull
```

**org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull**

> The @NotNull annotation is, actually, an explicit contract declaring
>   that:
>
> - A method should not return null
> - Variables (fields, local variables, and parameters) cannot hold a null value

Usage:

[image: intellij @NotNull]

**javax.validation.constraints.NotNull**

```
@Target(value={METHOD,FIELD,ANNOTATION_TYPE,CONSTRUCTOR,PARAMETER})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy={})
public @interface NotNull
```

**javax.annotation.Nonnull**

```
@Documented
@TypeQualifier
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public @interface Nonnull
```

Usage:

[image: javax @Nonnull]

---

So feel free to use any one of these four on your method.

Comment: Just to add javax.annotation.Nonnull, edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.NonNull,

Comment: Seems lombok developers refused to add check for non-null return value: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/907

Comment: @rkosegi The umd documentation is on sourceforge, which my company blocks. If you can add the appropriate documentation I would be grateful.

Comment: Wow! [Java Validation 2.0 works on method return values](http://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints)! Seems that it is not possible to express non-null return value in Java types. Java type system is not enough smart. **The only way is to go with static code analysis tools**.

Comment: @gavenkoa Exactly. It sounds like you want Kotlin. [Null was a mistake](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12427069)

Answer (score 0):

you can use .OrElse(). See this example

```
Optional<String> response = Optional.of("Not Null");
    Optional<String> response2 = Optional.empty();
    System.out.println(response.orElse(""));
    System.out.println(response2.orElse("Dont want to return null"));
```