# @NonNull annotation allows null values in validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, lombok

I have the following method in my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/register")
    public String registerNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(user);
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("***ERROR***");
            System.out.println(result.getAllErrors());
            return result.getAllErrors().toString();
        } else {
            //userRepository.save(user);
            System.out.println("user saved!");
            return "user saved!";
        }
    }
```

And my user entity specifies:

```
@NonNull
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
@Valid
public String alias;
```

Now if I make a simple post request (I use the Advanced REST client for chrome extension)  I get:

```
org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 0 errors
User(id=null, email=null, password=null, enabled=false, firstName=null, lastName=null, fullName=null null, alias=null, roles=[], links=[])
user saved!
```

Where it seems to validate despite @NonNull alias being null.

If I change @NonNull to @NotEmpty

Then validation works as expected:

```
[Field error in object 'user' on field 'alias': rejected value [null]; codes [NotEmpty.user.alias,NotEmpty.alias,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [user.alias,alias]; arguments []; default message [alias]]; default message [must not be empty]]
```

BUT what I don't understand is why @NonNull allows Nulls?

Comment: What package do you have `NotNull` from?

Comment: Project Lombok import

Comment: Should be from javax.validation package, I guess.

Comment: Ah ok I see, that would make sense. So if I want to use both I should use the full package name for one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `NotNull` from javax.validation package and not from lombok (those are to be deleted, when java starts supporting validation - see [here](https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/NonNull.html)). It validates the beans. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html). You can also use hibernate's `@NotNull` from org.hibernate.validator. This also does validation.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `@NonNull` annotation in the JSR-303 validation API. The annotation is called `@NotNull`. Make sure you actually use the `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull` annotation to mark the field.

Answer (score 2):

> **javax.validation.constraints**

---

`@NotNull:` The annotated element must not be null.Accepts any type

`@NotEmpty:` The annotated element must not be null nor empty. Supported types are:

- CharSequence (length of character sequence is evaluated)
- Collection (collection size is evaluated)
- Map (map size is evaluated)
- Array (array length is evaluated)

`@NotBlank:`The annotated element must not be null and must contain at least one non-whitespace character. Accepts CharSequence

---

```
@NonNull refer to Lombok
```

Here are the Great Details which you may like [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)