# @NotNull Deprecated in Antlr 4.6+ What to use instead?

Tags: java, annotations, antlr, antlr4, notnull

I'm building a parser using Antlr 4.8, and the @NotNull annotation is marked as deprecated:

*org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc
Annotation Type NotNull
Deprecated. 
THIS IS HERE FOR BACKWARD COMPATIBILITY WITH 4.5 ONLY. It will disappear in 4.6+*

I have searched but haven't found any documentation on what would replace this annotation. Obviously it hasn't disappeared in 4.6+, but I'd like to avoid issues as I move to new versions of Antlr.

Anyone know if there is a replacement for this annotation?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use

Comment: you can use NonNull annotation instead
check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use#:~:text=gives%20an%20overview%3A-,Package,-FIELD

Answer (score 1):

You can use @NonNull via

```
import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.NonNull;
```

Here's the import if you're using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>checker-qual</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you are using Antler 4.8 for your project, you'll want to set the version of the antlr4-maven-plugin that you are using to version 4.8.

Setting it to 4.6 also got rid of the error, but really I think it makes sense to keep the antlr plugin and runtime at the same version.