# IntelliJ does't have @NotBlank

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

So im running my program and I need to setup `@NotNull` from `import javaz.validation.constraints.NotBlank;`
All there is

```
 @NonNull
    private final String firstName;
```

and `import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;`

How do I install **@NotNull** or is **@NonNull** the same thing?

Comment: I don't really understand, what is the actual problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which @NotNull Java annotation should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use) should answer your question.

Short answer: there is a subtle difference, but it all depends on what you want, so you either need to read the post I've linked above or tell us more information.

Comment: Im just to download @NotBlank on my program but it not found