# why isn't @NotBlank not showing up as an import

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, javax.validation

Having an issue with my code

[image]
[image]
package com.example.demoSpring.student;

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

**import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;**
import java.util.UUID;

public class Students {
    private final UUID studentId;

    **@NotBlank**
    private final String firstName;

    **@NotBlank**
    private final String lastName;

    **@NotBlank**
    private final String email;

    @NonNull
    private final Gender gender;

    public Students(@JsonProperty("studentId") UUID studentId,
                    @JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
                    @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
                    @JsonProperty("email") String email,
                    @JsonProperty("gender") Gender gender) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public UUID getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Students{" +
                "studentId=" + studentId +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", gender=" + gender +
                '}';
    }

    enum Gender{
        MALE,FEMALE
    }

}
```

It's telling me that import javaz.validation.contraints.NotBlank doesn't exist, How do I install these on my IntelliJ

Im working on a project and I been having issues with this any import would be helpful, I'm using postman.
it just every time I check import javax.**validation**.constraints.NotBlank; is red I check options add dependency I get no result maven when I click find jar on web cant find it. How can I import this into my IntelliJ program?

Also here is my pom.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoSpring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demoSpring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.16.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>demoSpring</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

I added this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>**javax.validation**</groupId>
    <artifactId>**validation-api**</artifactId>
    <version>**2.0.1.Final**</version>
</dependency>
```

but the bold area is red dependency isn't found for these
[image]

Im still getting an error when I try to input dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Remove the `validation-api` dependency and add `spring-boot-starter-validation` as a dependency (before Spring Boot 2.3 this was automatically added with `spring-boot-starter-web` but it has been changed to not automatically add this anymore!). On a different note `assertj` and `HikariCP` are already added by default so you can remove those dependencies as well. ]

Comment: And please don't ask [the same question again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62626075/intellij-doest-have-notblank) (just because you aren't satisfied with the answer, instead edit the question to provide more details!).

Comment: M. Deinum new to being a Stackoverflow user. I'll make sure to not repeat the same question. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Spring Boot project, I added "validation-api" but postman was not throwing error and it allowed to store Blank fields (@NotBlank was not working).
Then I used this -

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add validation-api dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there any where in the pom.xml? cause Ive added it and It not working

Comment: did you try reimporting the project?

Comment: re-importing the project into IntelliJ? or creating the project from scratch again?

Comment: you should see a refresh icon in on top right when you open and update `pom.xml`

Comment: When I refresh pom.xml will I lose anything?

Comment: no, you will be just reimporting the maven project in intellij. it updates the classpath in opened project. saved files don't get updated

Comment: Adding an API will make it compile but without an implementation it doesn't do anything.

Comment: To use this class as the nullable/not null annotation you will also need to add it to corresponding inspection configuration: Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Inspections | Java | Probable bugs | Nullability problems | **@NotNull/@Nullable problems** -> **Configure Annotations**.

Comment: Thanks Audrey. You’re the best in the biz, Audrey, Sidgate, and M Deinum! https://youtu.be/3mLsU46h8IA

Comment: Still having an issues after pressing the Maven reload button

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add this dependency:

`<dependency>  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>  </dependency>`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).