# IntelliJ IDEA - Java annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

I've been using Android Studio (that is based on IntelliJ IDEA), and fine with using annotations such as @NonNull.

In addition to Android Studio, I installed IntelliJ IDEA.  I found that   annotations such as @NonNull are not working.  When I build the project, I got the error message:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class NonNull
  location: class Main
```

Could you show me how to enable the standard annotations in IntellJ IDEA?

[Edit 1]:

In IntelliJ IDEA:
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Configure annotations -> org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull already checked.

[Edit 2]:

In Eclipse:
I have no problems using the @NonNull annotation.  I ran into the same problem of unresolved annotation symbol in Eclipse at the beginning, however, the quick fix tips popped up on Eclipse (when I pointed the cursor to the unresolved symbol) helped me fix the problem.

By clicking the quick fixes:

- Eclipse added "org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_2_2.600.v2020408-1511.jar"
  under Referenced Libraries.
- Also, Eclipse added "requires org.eclipse.jdt.annotation;" in
  module-info.java.

At the time of writing, I haven't been able to get @NonNull working in IntelliJ.

Comment: There are multiple NonNull annotations available? Which one are you referring to? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use

Comment: whats your jdk version?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.  My issue was about using regular Java annotations in IntelliJ IDEA.  Here is the solution.

- Project Structure -> Libraries -> the 'plus' button -> From Maven -> org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2 -> OK
- In the Java code, use @NotNull (instead of @NonNull)
- In the Java code, import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

Besides, I was asked which JDK version that I used.  I've been experimenting some latest Java features by using JDK 14.0.2.

Here is my code example:

```
Function<String, Boolean> checkFavoriteDrink = (@NotNull var drink) -> {
    return switch (drink) {
        case "mocha", "cappuccino", "iced tea" -> true;
        default -> false;
    };
};
```