# What @Nullable to use in Java (as of 2023/JDK21)?

Tags: java, nullable, java-21

As of 2023/JDK21, what `@Nullable` to use in Java?

Many online materials don't even mention which import to use.
So it is now (dark) history in what order those annotation appeared.

[image: currentUserGroups]

I hope for general answer and from a reputable source (please quote documentation). For JDK21 some article could do as well.

For example `javax.annotation.Nullable` may be preferred. But at what version was it introduced? (We use JDK17, maybe next year some projects update to JDK21)

Comment: The `@Nullable` annotation doesn't do anything by itself. It's up to whatever product uses it to specify how it uses it. For example, IntelliJ IDEA will treat a field or argument as nullable if it has any kind of `@Nullable` annotation, irrespective of what package it comes from. Other software may be more choosy about which one you need to use. Also, note that the JDK doesn't know anything about this annotation. There is no JDK version that contains `javax.annotation.Nullable` - it's up to whoever is interested to actually define it.

Comment: Please don't fear to give votable/bountiable answer.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use) answer your question?

Comment: Also, this is basically a duplicate of [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4963300/341772), with the caveat that javax annotations are getting phased out in favor of similar [jakarta annotations](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/annotations/).

Comment: Eek! We had 14 different types of `@Nullable` annotations, now Jakarta comes along and we have 15.

Comment: Also, it's interesting how the StackOverflow community has changed its attitude over the years. The "duplicate" question has 1294 upvotes and not a single downvote and has stayed open after 12 years, yet this new question was downvoted immediately after posting and closed within the hour. Sometimes it's better to ask a new question as old questions can have grossly outdated answers that can't really be updated easily.

Comment: Those Jakarta annotations are for web development (Java Enterprise Edition).  I'd be surprised if they were in fact being favored over the `javax` ones.

Comment: @k314159 please vote for reopen. This question from the begging asks for modern 2023 solution with links to documentation. @ ParSal @ Max Yes, indeed, old question should be referenced.

Comment: How is this not a library recommendation request?

Comment: @markspace anything `javax` has license problems AFAIK, so to my understanding, `jakarta` is aiming to replace it in all possible contexts, not just web apps.

Comment: "`javax`" is the package Oracle uses for many Java API classes.  It's under the same license as the rest of Java.  I don't know what you're thinking of, but there's no license problems with it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/package-summary.html

Comment: @markspace from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE#History : "_The Eclipse Foundation could not agree with Oracle over the use of javax and Java trademarks._" I honestly wasn't interested in legal details myself, but I strongly believe that all the package renaming was not "just for fun", but because of important legal reasons.

Comment: @markspace maybe my first comment was ambiguous: I did **not** mean that merely **using** official `javax` classes from Oracle is in violation of any license, I meant that any 3rd parties (such as Eclipse Jakarta project) cannot add/modify anything there and thus `javax.annotation.Nullable` (and many others) are in violation (as also stated in the answer below by @mernst)

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me, that `jakarta.annotation.Nullable` from [jakarta.annotation-api](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/jakarta.annotation/jakarta.annotation-api/) is the closet to being "the standard". The old [javax.annotation repo](https://github.com/javaee/javax.annotation) links to [its sources](https://github.com/jakartaee/common-annotations-api) and as pointed in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76630457/what-nullable-to-use-in-java-as-of-2023-jdk21#comment135187686_76637175), the ever popular checker framework will deal with it.

In terms of adoption, it appears in [~30k files on github](https://github.com/search?q=jakarta.annotation.N&type=code) as of 09/2023 but I guess this number will grow quickly as more Servlet projects migrate to newer versions of the spec (`javax.annotation.N` currently matches [>1M files](https://github.com/search?q=javax.annotation.N&type=code), hard to guess however how many of them are Servlet related and how many of those will be migrated).

Answer (score 4):

In 2023, the best choice for the [`@Nullable`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/Nullable.html) and [`@NonNull`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/NonNull.html) annotation remains that of the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/).
It is the de facto standard (`import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual...` appears in [75k files on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual&type=code)), is recognized by the widest variety of tools, is a superset of most other nullness annotations, and has a clear, standard semantics.

The annotation is useful for a variety of purposes.

- You can write it as concise, precise documentation.
- You can use a tool to verify or to heuristically check that documentation.  Examples include:

  - The Checker Framework's [Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-checker) is the most comprehensive and can be [configured](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-lint) to be sound or lenient.  The Checker Framework also supports many [other type systems](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#introduction).
  - [NullAway](https://github.com/uber/NullAway) is a simpler tool that supports only nullness checking and that runs faster than the Nullness Checker.
  - Many others.
- Some automated test frameworks respect the annotation when generating tests.

Your question mentions `javax.annotation.Nullable`.  That annotation is not approved by Oracle and was never authorized to use the `javax` namespace (it did so in violation of the Oracle Java binary license).  The tool that introduced it, FindBugs, has been abandoned.

There is no official answer to your question that is blessed by Oracle.  JSR 305, whose goal was to define such an annotation, was abandoned and (according to my conversation with Mark Reinhold, who is the Chief Architect of the Java Platform Group at Oracle), Oracle is not interested in reviving it.  Every `@Nullable` annotation is provided by a third-party library and is ignored by `javac`.  The annotation is read only by third-party tools, such as annotation processors.

Comment: The checkerframework will care for the `@Nullable` and `@NonNull` annotations of the other frameworks too, when they exist, and likewise, most checking tools either respect all those annotations or are configurable regarding which annotations to check for, so in the end, it doesn’t really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another nullness annotation , [*jspecify*](https://jspecify.dev), is being created by a group led by Google:

EISOP Team,
Google,
JetBrains,
Meta    ,
Microsoft   ,
Oracle  ,PMD Team   ,
Sonar   ,
Square  ,
Uber    ,
VMware  .

They aim to create a tool-independent nullness annotation standard.

They list the reasons to (eventually) use it in their [FAQ](https://github.com/jspecify/jspecify/wiki/jspecify-faq)

- consensus
- precisely defined
- less strict than the awesome checker framework (complex, hard to migrate, false positives)
- not tool-specific