# Java: Spotbugs-Annotation `@CheckForNull` deprecated. What to use instead?

Tags: java, annotations, deprecated, static-analysis, spotbugs

In order to help my static code analysis, I have used the `@CheckForNull` -Annotation from spotbugs: edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.CheckForNull

It has come to my awareness that this annotation though still working, is officially deprecated.
What would you use in terms of best practice instead?

Best wishes
Abegail

Searched google and forums, but cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here:  [What @Nullable to use in Java (as of 2023/JDK21)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76630457/what-nullable-to-use-in-java-as-of-2023-jdk21)

In brief:

The best choice for the [`@Nullable`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/Nullable.html) and [`@NonNull`](https://checkerframework.org/api/org/checkerframework/checker/nullness/qual/NonNull.html) annotation remains that of the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/).
It is the de facto standard (`import org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual...` appears in [95k files on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual&type=code)), is recognized by the widest variety of tools, is a superset of most other nullness annotations, and has a clear, standard semantics.

Comment: Thanks!

Regarding the `@Nullable` annotation, this is treated the same as not being annotated?
See here:
https://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/annotations.html

Regarding the `@NonNull`-annotation:
Will the cause a warning using for instance SonarLint or Spotbugs when a method is annotated with this annotation and a method-call if this method is being dereferenced? 
The `@CheckForNull` annotation does so reliably. Isn't there a real new non-depracated `@CheckForNull` annotation somwhere?

Again, thanks a lot so far!

Comment: `@NonNull` is the default, and in most places is equivalent to no annotation, in most places other than some type bounds.  Most tools recognize many nullness annotations, including those of the Checker Framework.  (See [annotations supported by the Nullness Checker](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#nullness-related-work).)  FindBugs has been abandoned, as has JSR 305 which attempted to standardize the FindBugs annotations and semantics.

Comment: Thank you again! I just wonder what is the use of this annotation when it is mostly considered as no annotation at all? Will SonarLint not provide a hint when I annotate a method with this annotation and the dereference at some place in my codebase this method-call? With the @CheckForNull annotation SonarLint would provide a warning and recommend a null check.

Comment: I don't know how SonarLint works.  If it doesn't support an annnotation, you could ask its developers to do the (trivial) work of supporting it.

Comment: Have done and waiting for their reply.

But independently of that, I do not get what the use case of the `@NonNull` annotation is, when it is treated as being not annotated at all? Why then annotating something with this annotation?

Comment: That is a different question that should be answered elsewhere rather than in these comments.  Briefly, the fact that one specific tool (say, JUnit or JaCoCo or SonarLint) ignores an annotation does not mean that the annotation is pointless, when it is used by other tools.