Why are Checker Framework annotations not returned by Field#getDeclaredAnnotations?
I wanted to extend a bit of code that processes annotations to also support the Nullable annotation from the Checker Framework. To my surprise, this didn't work. Upon further inspection, it seems like the Checker Framework annotation is never picked by by reflection, even though meta-annotated with @Retention(RUNTIME).
class AnnotationTest {
    @javax.annotation.Nullable
    Object javax;

    @jakarta.annotation.Nullable
    Object jakarta;

    @org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable
    Object checker;

    @Test
    void annotations() {
        final Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (final Field field : fields) {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + " annotated with " + Arrays.toString(field.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
        }
    }
}

Output:
javax annotated with [@javax.annotation.Nullable()]
jakarta annotated with [@jakarta.annotation.Nullable()]
checker annotated with []

It is a Spring Boot project and it doesn't matter if the test is executed with IntelliJ or Gradle. Why are the other annotations picked up, but not the Checker Framework annotation?
For completeness sake, here's the definition of the annotation:
@SubtypeOf({})
@ImplicitFor(literals = LiteralKind.NULL, typeNames = java.lang.Void.class)
@DefaultInUncheckedCodeFor({TypeUseLocation.RETURN, TypeUseLocation.UPPER_BOUND})
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) // <-- retained at runtime!
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
public @interface Nullable {}


It's there. You're asking the wrong node.
javax.annotation.Nullable and checker's nullable are completely different. This is a general trend: There are ~15 frameworks with nullity annotations and none of them are the same. It's a big mess.
For what it is worth, checkerframework is more correct and most others are less correct. The reason they are wrong is possibly incompetence (hey, this stuff is way more complicated than it seems like), but more likely: Backwards compatibility.
Java 1.5 started with the annotations; the target TYPE_USE wasn't a thing back then. Later on (1.8?), TYPE_USE was introduced. Checkerframework either was started after TYPE_USE was available, or made a backwards incompatible update to move to it. javax/jakarta's nonnull predates it (or was designed by someone who didn't know what they were doing / has a wildly different idea of what non-null even means conceptually - but I think it predates).
These are the 2 completely different notions of nullity here:
TYPE_USE
The key difference is that checkerframework correctly states that it is targeted solely at types: @Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE). This is 'the new one'. That means given:
@Nullable private String foo;

The node that @Nullable applies to is just the String part. The field has no annotations here. None at all.. The field has a type and that has an annotation.
This conceptual notion of null is one that expands the type system itself. Any type has a nullity status.
The downside of this view is that its complicated in terms of generics. Just like there are 4 different ways to express 'list of numbers' in terms of generics:

List<? extends Number>
List<? super Number>
List<Number>
List (legacy / raw mode)

You need at least 4 levels of nullity (think of a method that accepts a List<String> and we are discussing the nullity of String)

non-null string: When reading from the list, the code does not need to nullcheck. When writing to it, only string refs that are necessarily non-null are allowed. Only List<@NonNull String> may be passed to this method.
nullable strings: Dereferencing refs read from the list isn't allowed without nullchecking. However, you can write whatever you want (null is fine, strings are fine). You can pass a List<@Nullable String> to this method.
legacy/raw: You can do whatever. (Current java code will have to be in legacy/raw mode. The JDK sources itself don't use nullity annotations after all).
'either way': The method will do both: It will ensure it never derefs what it reads / always nullchecks first, and it will ensure it never writes to the list / only writes known non-null entities. This method therefore needs to do the most work, but, in trade, it gets to accept both a List<@Nullable String> as well as a List<@NonNull String>. Which can be very useful, and is not expressible by any nullity framework... except.... checker-framework! Which allows this with @PolyNull, more or less.

Just like generics, this stuff is intrinsically complicated. It just is, so while this view of nullity is all sorts of difficult, it is an accurate representation of how things work, and thus, 'correct'.
ElementType.FIELD
In contrast, an annotation can state that it applies to fields, methods, and method parameters. In that case, if you write:
@Nullable private String foo;

The field has an annotation and its type doesn't.
This is a completely different view of nullity. You're just annotating whether a field/method's return value/parameter allows null or does not. It is not possible to get into details. You can't convey the concept of a list of non-nullable sets containing nullable strings. Because you can't carry this nullity concept into generics, it isn't composable and therefore you cannot possibly get to a world where every type at every location has known nullity.
But it is simple.
More generally type use is just 'correct', in that you can of course have a nullable list of non-nullable sets containing nullable strings. Which you can express with TYPE_USE but cannot express without it.
The confused thing: Both
The javax/jakarta nullility annotations don't have a @Target annotation. That means their target is 'everything except type parameters' (because the JLS says that's what 'no @Target annotation' means).
Therefore jakarta's annotations don't actually explain what that annotation even means 'this cannot be null', sure, but, the 'this' in that sentence is ambiguous.
In the case where an annotation can apply to both types and fields/methods/parameters (such as jakarta's), this code becomes ambiguous:
public @Nullable String field;

Given that the annotation can apply both to the field as a whole as well as the the field's type specifically, how is one to interpret this code? As per the compiler's specs, in such a case, the annotation applies to both. Both field.getAnnotations() as well as field.getAnnotatedType().getAnnotations() will find it, and indeed it's as if you wrote @Nullable public {@Nullable String} field (two separate things both annotated), except of course that's not legal java syntax.
This seems great, except, it isn't: You now have 2 mostly unrelated completely different ways to analyse nullity. You don't want that.
Can you see it?
Sure!
field.getAnnotatedType().getDeclaredAnnotations()

is what you're looking for.

Thank you for the extensive answer! While I know that I could do List<@Nullable String> with the Checker Framework, but not with the other annotations, I wasn't aware that this has implications when applied to fields (although I have to admit, it kinda makes sense). So I cannot annotate the field itself with the Checker Framework (but can with jakarta)? I always try to stay clear of the javax annotation and mostly tried to stick with the CF annotations. I wonder why the (newer) jakarta annotations are not TYPE_USE too, they came into existence much later than CF.

Because the jakarta annotations seem like a sensible way forward (they are not in the "wrong" package like the javax nullable annotations) and seem to have generally good support nowadays. The problem with the CF annotations in this case is that I don't have control over the getDeclaredAnnotations() part – I only get the already-resolved annotations from the library. The MRE in the question was simply to showcase the issue. Guess I'll stick with jakarta for now (which seems to be supported by CF anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76979277/112968)

I guess that I somehow assumed or hoped that (top-level) type annotations would propagate to the field itself

@knittl indeed, the @Nullable annotation can only be applied to types, and therefore not fields, methods, or method params (... you annotate the field's type, the method's return type, or the method parameter's type). It's a really fundamental mindset thing - a completely different understanding of what nullity even means. You MUST choose! Either [A] your understanding of nullity as a concept is a thing that applies to, and ONLY to, fields/methods/method params and nothing else, OR [B] it applies ONLY to types, where-ever they appear.

Frameworks that attempt to do both (such as jakarta/javax) are bad and you should not use them. Further highlighting why javax/jakarta nullity annos are bad : Without a @Target annotation, they can apply to both 'sides' (types AND fields/methods/params), but not type params which is bizarre. jakarta is incapable of representing the nullity properties of map's get.

The fact that the stupid one (jakarta) has a lot of support is correct, and a painful fact. Nevertheless, because its such a confused project with a nonsensical understanding of the concept, I strongly advise you to use an annotation system that isn't confused. Either one whose annos are targeted to apply only to types (@NonNullByDefault applies to classes/packages/modules, that part is fine), or one whose annos are targeted to only apply to fields/methods/params. CheckerFramework is a 'targets types' one, and the most academically rigorous system in the ecosystem.

I'm going to slightly update my answer; the fact that jakarta's annotations cannot apply to type params is fine, I slightly misunderstood what that is for. The fact that jakarta's can apply both to types as well as elements is still indicative of a confused understanding of nullity and will inevitably lead to ambiguity when attempting to even reason about what these annotations imply.

Thanks for the colorful response comments. Re: "I strongly advise you to use an annotation system that isn't confused." – I tried to (I favor Checker Framework for my own code), but often you will need to use libraries which only support annotations on the field, not on the annotated type of the field. In such a case, I have to fall back to the annotation from jakarta or add both annotations (one or both fully qualified). And I worked with a project, which explicitly forbids using Checker Framework annotations and lets the CI build fail if non-jakarta nullable annotations are used.

Well, there's little for me to say other than 'try not to work with projects that enforce use of badly designed libraries' ;) - but if you're forced into it, at least it's good to know the problems you're going to end up running into.

The reason is that the Checker Framework's Nullable is a type qualifier:

@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})

It is a bug that the javax version (illegally placed in the javax namespace by the abandoned JSR 305 project) and the jakarta version are declaration qualifiers, since nullness is a quality of a type, not a declaration.
You can verify that the @Nullable annotation appears on the type by running the following code:
import java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Arrays;

class AnnotationTest {

  @org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable Object checker;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Field[] fields = AnnotationTest.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (final Field field : fields) {
      System.out.println("field " + field.getName() + " annotated with "
              + Arrays.toString(field.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
      AnnotatedType atype = field.getAnnotatedType();
      System.out.println(
          "type " + atype.getType() + " annotated with "
              + Arrays.toString(atype.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
    }
  }
}

whose output is
field checker annotated with []
type class java.lang.Object annotated with [@org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.qual.Nullable()]


Try the following in the annotations method:
@Test
void annotations() {
    final Field[] fields = getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (final Field field : fields) {
        // direct annotations
        System.out.println(field.getName() + " annotated with " + Arrays.toString(field.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
        
        // type-use annotations
        AnnotatedType annotatedType = field.getAnnotatedType();
        System.out.println("Type-use annotations on " + field.getName() + ": " + Arrays.toString(annotatedType.getDeclaredAnnotations()));
    }
}


Please don't post code-only answers. Explain what you changed and why.
