# Is there a way to indicate if we are exceeding a certain size limit on certain fields

Tags: eclipse

I have a description field of a certain entity, which has a runtime limitation of 255 characters.
e.g.  `class Foo { String description; }`

When I create several Foo's, I need a mechanism by which the editor can tell me that I am exceeding size limit on description. Is there a way to do this, since I capture most of these issues only during runtime (i.e. when the underlying ORM provider throws an error) and I would prefer to capture this while editing itself.

Comment: Are u using ORM tools  like hibernate?

Comment: Not precisely what you're asking for, but some of the tools in this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998553/how-to-assert-something-at-compile-time-in-java/998577#998577

Comment: @harigm - I am using Hibernate as the ORM runtime.

Comment: @OpenSauce - ORM providers perform validation checks prior to storing the object (e.g. Foo foo;). My requirement is to catch such errors while creating such entities (e.g. Foo foo1 = new Foo("String of size 25"); Foo Foo2 = new Foo("String of size 300"). I wan't the editor to show me a warning for foo2, so that I don't need to wait until the error is thrown by the runtime. Hope it's clear

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but you can limit the text entered into a `Text` control using `text.getTextLimit(255)`...

Comment: Nope, this is not what I am looking for. See my comments for @OpenSauce